# Should one use many small configuration files for script or a single large configuration file?

Tags: linux, scripting

I have a script which starts from [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) with regular interval and sources in around 10 variables. Should I keep those 10 variables in one configuration file in file system or is it a better practice to keep a separate configuration file for each variable? What are the advantages of one approach over another?

Comment: It would be difficult to comprehensively answer without a better understanding of your job and what it does. That said, 10 files for a single job would be excessive. One config file would be normal. If specialized enough (and not redistributed), it may be fine to leave the variables in source.

Comment: Much like software objects, the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is valid for configuration files or file sections. Polling for opinions is off-topic here: have you given thought to one approach over the other? Do you have specific concerns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would tell you to go to the single file approach, because the other approach (many single-variable files) is **at least extremely unorthodox**.

The advantage of the single file approach, which has been used successfully for decades, is that all configuration settings of a program (or aspect of a program*) can be moved together to another location, compared with another version of the file, etc.

As [Kilian Foth mentioned](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/287308/should-one-use-many-small-configuration-files-for-script-or-a-single-large-confi#comment592986_287310):

> Using one file for each value is essentially abusing the file system as a data base. Don't do that. Both files systems and databases are good at what they do, and not so good at doing the other's job.

I would summarize it by stating that ease of use, ease of implementation and ease of maintenance are the main advantages of grouping related config settings in a single file compared to having many files, each containing one single setting.

(*) some programs have multiple conf files, but each one contains a set of related settings, not just one setting.

Comment: Mostly true: some programs have their own directories containing multiple configuration files. That being said, each file contains a grouping of related variables, not individual variables.

Comment: @Snowman I improved the answer by mentioning that some apps have multiple conf files, each one holding settings related to one specific aspect or module of the app.

Comment: Using one file for each value is essentially abusing the file system as a data base. Don't do that. Both files systems and databases are good at what they do, and not so good at doing the other's job.

Comment: Think about it:  If you use a bunch of separate files then you have no ability to search for the setting you're after and have to look in every file to find it.